# How do I move a picture behind text in Excel header?

Tags: excel-online

When you insert a header into Excel you get three bars to work with; left, middle and right. I wish to insert a banner picture into the middle bar and the text shown is:

```
&[Picture]
```

In the left bar I wish to have the actual header being `My Excel Spreadsheet`.
All in all, I want the text to be in front of the image on the header.

Please note this is Excel Online, and Microsoft Excel works in a similar fashion, so if you know how to do it in Microsoft Excel it may help.